# Ch.5 Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby: What is endertromb?

Tags: ruby

Can some one help me understand how 'endertromb' is being used or where I can get it for this guide?
http://poignant.guide/book/chapter-5.html

Why has 2 examples where he is trying to teach a concept about instance variables but he seems to be requesting a file endertromb.rb and using it. Am I missing something? what/how can I get this file so that I don't get errors. I've tried to Google but got nothing at all.
Heres example code of how he used it:

```
require 'endertromb'
 class WishMaker
   def initialize
     @energy = rand( 6 )
   end
   def grant( wish )
     if wish.length > 10 or wish.include? ' '
       raise ArgumentError, "Bad wish." 
     end
     if @energy.zero?
       raise Exception, "No energy left." 
     end
     @energy -= 1
     Endertromb::make( wish )
   end
 end
```

Comment: Why don't you write your own `Endertromb` class in a file named `entertromb.rb` (and change the first line to `require_relative 'endertromb'` for Ruby 1.9.2)?

Comment: although I was aware I could make my own Endertromb I wasn't sure what to do with the Endertromb::make( wish ) part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Endertromb` is just a class defined in another file, and thats all you need to know. As stated by _why himself in this guide:

> Both the wish maker and the mind
>   reader refer to a class named
>   Endertromb. This class is stored in a
>   file endertromb.rb, which is loaded
>   with the code: require 'endertromb'.

and

> The Endertromb class which contained
>   the mysteries of this planet’s powers.

Answer (score 4):

Endertromb is a class defined in the file endertromb.rb , therefore the "require 'endertromb'".

> Both the wish maker and the mind reader refer to a class named
>   Endertromb. This class is stored in a
>   file endertromb.rb, which is loaded
>   with the code: require 'endertromb'.
>   Often you’ll use other classes to
>   accomplish part of your task. Most of
>   the latter half of this book will
>   explore the wide variety of helpful
>   classes that can be loaded in Ruby.

Code for this class seems to be absent in the guide (or at this part, maybe it's defined later).

Comment: …or perhaps _Why was pointing out that sometimes you just require and use other libraries as black boxes, without knowing or caring how they are implemented.

Comment: thats probably what he was doing. Having practically 0 programming experience it gets confusing when stuff like that isn't deliberately pointed out since we try to grasp how everything comes together. Thank goodness for stackoverflow :D